# How can I customize the download button for virtual/downloadable products in EDD and Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, easy-digital-downloads

In **EDD** and **Woocommerce** plugins, after purchasing virtual and downloadable products, the purchased products can be downloaded using the download button.

Is it possible to control or manage the commands of this button?

For example, if this button, which is different for each product, is clicked, it will display a message (display the ID number and name of the current product).

*[How to create a download file for a virtual downloadable product by clicking the download button of the purchased product?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76331468/how-to-create-a-download-file-for-a-virtual-downloadable-product-by-clicking-the)*